# What are the Galactic Orbits?

Tags: orbital-motion, galaxies

For some reason, I can't get an answer in Google.

I know the Galactic Orbits within the galactic plane are about circular, with constant angular velocity (which violates Kepler's laws, which is the reason we infer the dark matter's existence. Also, this angular velocity increases a bit at the edge of the galaxies). But what about orbits outside the galactic plane? do the stars there also orbit the galactic center with constant angular velocity?

I'm interested in facts, not speculation. That is, answers which partly reside on some assumption about (e.g.) the dark matter's density are of no interest to me.

Comment: The facts are that the shape of galactic orbits is a product of the galactic mass distribution, and about 90% of that mass is in the form of dark matter. Any answers are going to rely on assumptions about the dark matter distribution, whether you like it or not.

Comment: Galactic orbits take millions of years to complete. Obviously we have only measured them for perhaps a century at most, i.e. at best we measure a location and a velocity, but we never observe a significant amount of the orbit. Therefore, the orbit needs to be calculated. This calculation requires knowledge the potential. And that potential is dominated by dark matter. Thus, your question can not be answered as specified in your text. I suggest you re-evaluate what you mean by "fact" though...

Comment: There is no violation of Kepler's laws, which don't apply in any case when orbits are not around point masses. The linear velocity is what is approximately constant, not the angular velocity. Please re-formulate your question.

Comment: One problem in answering your question (which is reasonable) is that outside of the plane of the disc, most orbits are non-circular. Therefore the instantaneous angular (or linear) velocity is not going to be a single-valued function of distance from the Galactic centre, since it varies with time.

Comment: Thank you all. indeed my question was misformulated, but nevertheless your answers were tremendously helpful. I got answers to almost all the points that bothered me. But I just want to clarify one more thing: inside the disc, all stellar velocities are transverse (relative to the galaxy's center), while outside the disc, most of the stars have also a radial velocity, and that's all that can be said without assumptions on the (e.g.) dark matter distribution. Am I correct?

Comment: Nothing is so neat and tidy. The disk isn't a rigid object with stars fixed to it. Disk stars have relatively little random motion and roughly circular orbits, but their non-transverse motions are far from zero.